# Program crashes after trying to use a recently created file. C#

Tags: c#, file-io, streamwriter

So here is my code

```
if (!File.Exists(pathName))
{
    File.Create(pathName);
}
StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(pathName,true);
```

But whenever I run the program the first time the path with file gets created. However once I get to the StreamWriter line my program crashes because it says my fie is in use by another process. Is there something I'm missing between the File.Create and the StreamWriter statements?

Comment: are you sure no other process is accessing the file? check your task manager, one of your application's instance might be running.

Comment: Code from the department of redundancy department.

Answer (score 6):

[File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=VS.100).aspx) doesn't just create the file -- it also opens it for reading and writing. So the file is indeed already in use when you try to create the StreamWriter: by your own process.

[StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=VS.100).aspx) will create the file specified by `pathName` if it doesn't exist, so you can simply remove the `File.Exists` check and simplify your your code this:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(pathName, true))
{
   // ...
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=VS.100).aspx):

> **StreamWriter Constructor (Stream)**
>
> Initializes a new instance of the StreamWriter class for the specified file [...]. If the file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this constructor creates a new file.

Comment: Even that is too much, isn't it? He can just use a writer with the filename and a boolean to open for appending.

Comment: Easier to just create the `StreamWriter` with `new StreamWriter(pathName, true)`. That will create the file if it doesn't exist and append to it if it does. (Edit: I see @Anthony said the same thing :) ).

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, `File.Create` is creating a `FileWriter` that's holding your file open. But aside from that, there's no reason to check for file existence before trying to open the file. Just tell `File.Open` to open an existing file if one is there:

```
var outputFile = new StreamWriter(File.Open(pathName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
```

Comment: Good point about checking for existance. Not only pointless, it can actually make the application vulnarable to [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Answer (score 1):

After the File.Create the stream is still open.

You could use:

```
File.Create(pathName).Close();
```

This creates the file and closes it directly.

More accepted is:

```
using (var file = File.Create(pathName)) {
   // use the file here
   // it will be closed when leaving the using block
}
```

Also: Why do you create a file, that you create 2 lines further in your code? The [StreamWriter constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) (with append=true) will create or append the file if it does not exist.

Comment: Good question. And the answer is I don't know. I'm still new to C# and this is my experimentation program that I'm playing with.

Answer (score 0):

File.Create returns a FileStream. Why don't you save that and pass it to the StreamWriter constructor instead of passing a pathname?